# How do I make OnClick execute after OnClientClick in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET web forms application in C#. I have a button that needs to run some client-side Javascript (using the OnClientClick attribute), then run server-side code (using OnClick) if the client-side code returns true. I've done this plenty of times before with jQuery-ui confirmation dialogs, however this time my client-side code isn't a confirmation dialog and it isn't working -- the server-side (OnClick) event never gets triggered even though I'm explicitly returning true.

Here's the client-side code in question, which is working (I've verified that it's returning the correct value with an alert() call):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Function to hide edit fields
    function hideEditFields(retVal) {
        //Hide all edit divs
        var editName = document.getElementsByClassName("editField");
        for (i = 0; i < editName.length; i++) {
            editName[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        //Show all view divs
        var viewName = document.getElementsByClassName("viewField");
        for (i = 0; i < viewName.length; i++) {
            viewName[i].style.display = 'block';
        }

        //Make investigated & corrective action checkboxes non-highlighted
        $('<%=cbInvestigatedY.ClientID%>').removeClass("editable");
        $('<%=cbInvestigatedN.ClientID%>').removeClass("editable");
        $('<%=cbCorrectiveY.ClientID%>').removeClass("editable");
        $('<%=cbCorrectiveN.ClientID%>').removeClass("editable");

        //Show edit button
        var editButton = document.getElementById("editButton");
        editButton.style.display = 'block';
        //Hide save button
        var saveButton = document.getElementById("saveButton");
        saveButton.style.display = 'none';

        //alert("returning " + retVal);
        return retVal;
    }
</script>
```

And here's the button that calls this function:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveChanges" runat="server" OnClientClick="return 
    hideEditFields(true);" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Save Changes" />
```

I've tried this with `UseSubmitBehavior="true"` and without, which seems to make no difference. I'm getting no errors in the Javascript console, and the Javascript code is doing what it's supposed to do, it's just not calling the server-side method.

Here's how the submit button gets rendered (in view source) by ASP.NET:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSaveChanges" value="Save Changes"
    onclick="return hideEditFields(true);WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
    WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$btnSaveChanges&quot;, &quot;&quot;,
    true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))"
    id="ctl00_MainContent_btnSaveChanges" />
```

Comment: Is the form being submitted and the server is hit at all?

Comment: No, it's only executing the client-side code.

Comment: Are you able to view the actual source of the page and see exactly how the `asp:Button` is being rendered? Also, if you remove the `onClientClick` attribute, does the server get called correctly?

Comment: OK, I'm mistaken - my server call is getting called, it just isn't doing anything. I'll have to dig into it and probably post a new question when I figure out what's really going on. Thanks for your troubleshooting help.

Comment: Can you make an Ajax call to your server at the end of your JS function and not use a server event handler?

Comment: Hmm well from the source you posted, using `return` like you are, the rest of the `onclick` won't execute, whether it's true or false. That's why - those .NET function calls don't set up the submit to behave correctly so the server can know the trigger

Comment: @Ian I thought that was how ASP.NET worked - if the OnClientClick returns false it does not continue with the OnClick call and if OnClientClick returns true it does?

Comment: Usually when I call using asp.net controls through JS/jQuery I set ClientIDMode="Static" to the control. maybe try that

Comment: @timbck2 Well yeah, usually. Except it looks like it has to do special things to set up the postback, I'm guessing because it's in a GridView. I'm not sure why, but I've definitely gotten the confirm stuff to work in a GridView when I set the attribute on the server side. I'm starting up my example so I can see what the source looks like and if my project is comparable to yours

Comment: @Ian This is turning into a conversation and I guess that's frowned upon on StackExchange, but no, not in a GridView; it is in an AccordionPanel though, which may have some effect. At any rate, I have it working correctly now, thanks to you prompting me to realize where the real problem was.

Comment: @timbck2 Hmm I'm not sure why I thought a GridView...I must've been thinking of a different SO question. While conversations are frowned upon, we're directly talking about figuring out your problem, so I think that's fine. I'm glad you got it working though :) You should post an answer and accept it! I'd love to see how you fixed it

Comment: @timbck2 By the way, my setup was a GridView (which is comparable to an accordion, in this situation), but I was using LinkButtons. So my confirmation went in the `onclick` attribute, while .NET's automatic extra code went in the `href`, therefore allowing me to `return` in the `onclick` and prevent the submit/server stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem was that my server-side method **was** being executed, but was doing nothing, because it compares the original values in the form (stored as hidden fields) with the new values entered in the form's text boxes and other controls and stores them if they have changed. But I was making the noob mistake of not enclosing the code that populated the form in a check for IsPostBack (*and I know better!*), so the comparison was always coming out equal, so nothing was changing. See [Why is ASP.NET submitting the original value of a TextBox control when the contents have been changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301366/why-is-asp-net-submitting-the-original-value-of-a-textbox-control-when-the-conte) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Pleasea try to remove the `return` from calling in the client click. I think you should call the function `onclientclick` like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveChanges" runat="server" OnClientClick="hideEditFields('true');"  Text="Save Changes" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Answer (score 1):

On a client click, set the return value to true:

```
btnTest.OnClientClick = 
    "window.open('" + URL + "'); 
    return true;";
```